# Intercept in a dynamic panel model

Tags: regression, panel-data, consistency, intercept, dynamic-regression

I have been taught that including fixed/random effects in a dynamic panel model yields inconsistent estimates when using OLS and hence motivates the usage of other estimation methods.

However, does this also apply to the inclusion of a constant term, i.e. an intercept?

Comment: By “dynamic” you are referring to the presence of lagged dependent variable(s)? Correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly @ThomasBilach.